# Hide image gallery in Woocommerce if NO image

Tags: images, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a few products with no images but they template leaves a big empty space where the image should be, I was wondering if there was a way to hide this product gallery section only IF there are NO images uploaded to that product.

Thanks
Badger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce adds classes to indicate when a product has a thumbnail specified, so you can address this with CSS.

```
.product .images { display: none; } /* hide images div by default */
.product.has-post-thumbnail .images { display: block; } /* show images div when thumbnail is present */
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much, I had not noticed that at all :)

Comment: Where do I put this?

Comment: @PrimožKralj stylesheet of the active child theme or a custom CSS plugin, etc.